# How to read only the first value of a file, then go to the next line?

Tags: c

So I am writing a program that reads data from an input file and prints it out.

One of my tasks is to store the total number of records (10), and check which number reoccurs the most.

The sample input file consists of this;

`1265 -37.817365 144.968783 6/8/19 10 
 1726 -37.810009 144.962800 6/8/19 10 
 1726 -37.809657 144.965221 6/8/19 11 
 1726 -37.867842 144.976916 6/8/19 14 
 1328 -37.913256 144.985346 6/8/19 14 
 1265 -37.822464 144.968863 6/8/19 14 
 1654 -37.830386 144.979659 9/8/19 11 
 1726 -37.822464 144.968863 1/9/19 14 
 1654 -37.817365 144.968783 1/9/19 15 
 1408 -37.845590 144.971467 1/9/19 16`

Now the only number I want to be checking is the first value, and seeing which of these numbers comes up the most and printing that number. From this file, it would be number 1726.

I am new to arrays and storage, but this is what I have so far;

```
int i=0;
int num;
int integers [256];
while(fscanf(stdin, "%d", &num) > 0) {
    integers[i] = num;
    i++;
}
printf("\n%d", num);
```

Where do I go from here? I am pretty stuck and not sure how to achieve my desired outcome.

Comment: Read line by line line with `fgets` and then use `sscanf` upon that line.

Comment: would that be in a while loop? and how would I go about implementing that? Sorry just a little confused

Comment: You can drive the `while` loop with the return value from `fgets`. So `while(fgets(...) != NULL) {...}`

Comment: are you suggesting something like this? 
` while(fgets(line, 256, stdin)) {  
        integers[i] = sscanf("%d", line);
        i++;
    }`

Comment: Not quite: `sscanf` works pretty much like `fscanf` but the input is the string, not the file. But unlike `fscanf` you can ignore the rest of the input.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
...
int i=0;
int num;
int integers [256];
char linebuffer[100];
while(fgets(linebuffer, sizeof linebuffer, stdin) != NULL)
{
  if (sscanf(linebuffer, "%d", &num) == 1)
  {
    integers[i] = num;
    i++;
  }
}
...
```

This is untested code, there may be errors, but you should get the idea. Especially if the file has more than 256 lines you may get an array index overflow and hence undefined behaviour.

Comment: On a POSIX system, [`getline()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html) can be used to handle strings of arbitrary length.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you very much! and if I wanted to print each value, would i just write `printf("%d", num)`?

Comment: @HassSugma obviously yes. But I suggest rather `printf("%d\n", num)`. The `printf("\n%d", num);` in  your question OTH doesn't make much sense, it justs prints the last number read.